# Get all KeyPaths for an Object

Tags: swift, reflection, swift5, mirror, keypaths

Is there a way in Swift 5 to iterate over all keypaths? I'm aware `Mirror` will give you string representations of the keys, but I can't use `setValue` as my objects are not inherited from `NSObject` and several values are not `@objc` compatible. I am attempting to do something like the below (pseudo coded):

```
func overwrite(source:T, overwrite:T) {
  for keypath in overwrite.allKeypaths() {
    source[keyPath: keyPath] = overwrite[keyPath: keyPath]
  }
}
```

The end goal here is to create first a shallow copy into an existing object and possibly expand that out to include a deep copy based on the value type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Swift. There is no way to get all keypaths on a given object. You can, however, use `Mirror` to look all properties of an object to get the string representation of objective-c objects. However, not all value types can be set using `setValue` in this way, as not all Swift types translate to objective-c.